# What is the effect of covariance on the dynamics of a price

Tags: asset-pricing

I want to know how can I see covariance affecting the dynamics of the price of an asset. I understand what the value for covariance and it's sign, but I do not get how it plays in the bigger picture.  For example, I have the dynamics of the price of an asset:

[image]

This is a geometric Brownian motion. Is the covariance the volatility vector of the dynamics or is it in the dz term, which is a Weiner process?

I want to know how exactly covariance affects the dynamics and how to it relates to the other components.

Comment: covariance of what? Seems to me that you are describing a univariate process. Is that volatility vector indicating regimes? Else?

Comment: Usually, we say that the price covaries with some shocks. I want to know if this co-movement is denoted by the sigma. The dz term represents 2 shocks that propagate in the entire economy. How much the price is moving with respect to the shock is given by $\sigma$. Would that mean that $\sigma$ is the covariance?

What are those regimes which you mentioned? Would different regimes indicate different states of the economy i.e "boom" or "bane"?

Comment: as you said, sigma is how much the price moves with respect to shocks. The correlation is assumed to be upon the shocks. In fact, usually when you have multiple brownian motions, then the process is accompanied to an explanation of the correlation between different the brownian motions themselves. Yes, I meant regimes in Markov-Switching sense

Comment: What was a bit confusing to me is that you mention the dynamics of one asset, but the equation you present is for several assets, each denoted by the subscript i.